# How best to create and manipulate a map for a text based game F#

Tags: function, f#

Ok so this is how my code looks for my map as of now

```
let r58 = {id=58;item=pot2;n=0;e=0;s=51;w=0;complete=false}
let r59 = {id=59;item=m13;n=60;e=0;s=55;w=0;complete=false}
let row11 = [r58;r59]

let r60 = {id=60;item=m8;n=61;e=0;s=59;w=0;complete=false}
let r61 = {id=61;item=m9;n=0;e=0;s=60;w=0;complete=false}
let row12 = [r60;r61]

let roomlist = List.concat[row1;row2;row3;row4;row5;row6;row7;row8;row9;row10;row11;row12]

roomlist
```

The id is a reference to the room itself, the item is of type object, can hold potions, or a monster etc.NESW are for where the room leads.However I don't know how to process this, when they go into a room, the type of object stored should be found and processed accordingly.Bombs, monsters, and items are stored like so:

```
let bomb9 = {name="End point grenade";bVal=99.0;dType=General;info="Banned 
from use by enforcers of your rank for obvious reasons, a smaller, compact 
version of what they called a 'nuclear bomb' in the
        days of old";iSpace=2};

let bomb0 = {name ="Clairvoyance";bVal=0.0;dType=General;info="Its explosion 
reveals the truth behind items";
        iSpace=1}

let bombinit = 
  let bomblist = [bomb1;bomb2;bomb3;bomb4;bomb5;bomb6;bomb7;bomb8;bomb9;bomb0]
  bomblist
```

Thus they all have their own lists, I have a list of monsters, bombs, potions and rooms.
However my lecturer says I should use a dictionary for the rooms, to look like so:

```
    (frontOfHouse, {id=1; item=m1; n=backOfHouse;e=null;s=null;w=null;complete=false};
(backOfHouse, {id=2; item=bomb1; n=frontOfHouse; e=null;s=null;w=null;complete=false
```

However I have no idea how this is better than using the set of rooms within the list to allow users to transverse through the map.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am not accustomed to f#, if anyone would like to help more and see my whole code just give me a shout.

Much appreciated

Comment: This question is basically, "Is this a good design for my code, or can it be improved?" These kinds of questions are better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where more people will be prepared to answer "Help me improve my code" questions.

Comment: thanks I have posted there aswell, sorry, my lecturer wasn't really of any help, I'm struggling with f# , even though I found java, python and pascal completely fine !

Comment: F# feels very different from Java, Python and Pascal. In those languages, you think in terms of imperative *commands*: your programs are *telling* the computer what to do step by step. And you can also write F# in an imperative style, but you usually write F# in a more *declarative* style, where *expressions* rather than commands are the central concept, and you think of your program mostly in terms of what data comes in, what data goes out, and how that data is transformed. BTW, if you're having trouble thinking in F#, https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ is an excellent website to read.